# Adding ScriptPath to <asp:scriptmanager refreshes the page. How to stop the page from refreshing?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I am using a dropdown inside updatepanel and the problems is, page refreshes on selecting the value from my dropdown. Initially update panel was working fine, until i added ScripPath to asp:scriptmanager.

Even now, if i remove ScriptPath from scriptmanager the page doesn't refresh and the behaviour is as expected.

The reason why i add the ScriptPath is, i want to execute abc.js everytime the value is changed in dropdown. As expected the abc.js is executed for every selected value of my dropdown, but i dont want the page to be refreshed.

So, How to stop the page from refreshing even after adding scriptpath to asp:scriptmanager ?

The below is my .aspx source.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ScriptPath="abc.js"  runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> 

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Social_Ddl" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="styled-select">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Font-Size="Small" ToolTip="Social : 'ON' will post your activity on this page to your FaceBook Wall." Text="Social :" Style="vertical-align: top;" />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSocialSwitch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Style="vertical-align: top;" ToolTip="Social : ON will post your activity on this page to your FaceBook Wall." OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSocialSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                &nbsp;<a valign="bottom" onclick="logout_fb" href="#" id="auth-logoutlink"><img valign="bottom" src="facebookLogOutButton.png"/></a>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

JS

```
//Get values from hidden field
var appid = document.getElementById("appid").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
var link = document.getElementById("link").value;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var picture = document.getElementById("picture").value;
var description = document.getElementById("description").value;

var Authenticated = "";
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));

//Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: appid, // App ID
        channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML 
    });
    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
            var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
            FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;
            })
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';

            var e = document.getElementById("FB_ddlSocialSwitch");
            var Social_switch = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            if (Social_switch == "on") {
                alert(Social_switch);
            } 

            //_______________________________________________Post to FB_______________________________________________________
            //    var opts = {
            //        message: 'A good reference for APIs',
            //        link: window.location.href,
            //        name: 'API Reference',
            //        picture: 'http://www.demo.lookmywebpage.com/publish-on-facebook-wall/Google-Twitter-Facebook.jpg',
            //        description: 'Demo Facebook Post'
            //    };
            //  
            //    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function (response) {
            //        if (!response || response.error) {
            //            alert('Posting error occured');
            //        }
            //        else {
            //            alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
            //        }
            //    });
            //________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

        } else {
            // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
        }

    });
    $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () {
        FB.logout(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Share your js code, I am sure something is not right there

Comment: @nunespascal i have added the code in my js file. Do you think its because of the js file ? Even if i put an alert('hi') it dosent execute !!!

Comment: I do not see any code where you are listening to the `onchange` event of the select(DropDownList)

Comment: @nunespascal i the change events is done in server side

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using "ScriptPath". Set the **Path** property on each individual ScriptReference instead.

[ScriptPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): **Obsolete**. Gets or sets the root path of the location that is used to build the paths to ASP.NET Ajax and custom script files.

Eg.

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
                                 EnablePartialRendering="True"
                                 runat="server">
             <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/abc.js" />
             </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve my requirement then ? I want to execute the abc.js everytime the user selects a value from dropdown. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example on "Set the Path property on each individual ScriptReference instead"

Comment: I Used something like this...And it dosent work. The abc.js is not executing on selecting the value from dropdwon... <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/abc.js" />
</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: i tried with your example. But the abc.js doesn't execute on selecting the value from dropdown. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing this right. 
Keep your js script statically on the page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
                                 EnablePartialRendering="True"
                                 runat="server">
  <Scripts>
   <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/abc.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Listen to the [onChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange) event in javascript.
jQuery makes this easy:

```
$("#<%=ddlSocialSwitch.ClientID%>").change(function(e) {
      //handle the change
});
```

`OnSelectedIndexChanged` is a server side function, to execute js you should listen to the onchange event.

Comment: I am getting this error : 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not contain a definition for 'CliendID' and no extension method 'CliendID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is `ClientID` and not `CliendID`. Corrected the error

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the AutoPostback property from the dropdownlist control.  that will stop the postback and will just execute the javascript.  don't forget to add the javascript event handler to the dropdownlist's onchange event. You can probably remove the update panel, unless you need it to do a partial page postback, which from your description, doesn't sound like you do.

Best Regards.